# python selenium click on button without Id and name

Tags: python, selenium, selenium-webdriver

I have one button, and I want to click on this button , I do

```
login_form = driver.find_element_by_xpath("/html/body/div/h1/div[1]").click();
```

my code :

```
driver = webdriver.Firefox()
driver.get('http://www.textdet.com/')

e = driver.find_element_by_id("imagefile")                  
e.send_keys("/home/brm17/Desktop/ProjetFinDetude/image.png")  
login_form = driver.find_element_by_xpath("/html/body/div/h1/div[1]").click();
```

But I  get:

> selenium.common.exceptions.NoSuchElementException: Message: Unable to
>   locate element: /html/body/div/h1/div[1]

how to click on button `Download bounding boxes` on `python` by `selenium`  , the html

```
<h1 style="position: relative"><a href="/">Scene Text Detection Demos</a>

        <div aria-label="..." role="group" class="btn-group" style="position: absolute; bottom: 10px; right: 0px;">
            <!--<button id="toggle_text_propoals" type="button" class="btn btn-success btn-sm">Show text proposals</button>-->
            <a href="download_bboxes/acdb4bb9-8b73-4020-bfe5-737316033e5e" type="button" class="btn btn-success btn-sm">Download bounding boxes</a>
        </div>

      </h1>
```

Answer (score 2):

The button is in `<a>` tag, not `<div>` tag. You also have only one `<div>` so `div[1]` is invalid. You can search by the text

```
from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import WebDriverWait
from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as EC
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By

button = WebDriverWait(driver, 10).until(EC.visibility_of_element_located((By.XPATH, '//a[contains(., "Download bounding boxes")]')))
button.click();
```

Or by class since you have only one button so class `btn` should be unique.

```
driver.find_element_by_class_name('btn').click(); # or 'btn-success' or 'btn-sm'
```

By the way, `click()` doesn't return anything, you can't assign it to `login_form`.

Comment: Error `selenium.common.exceptions.NoSuchElementException: Message: Unable to locate element: //a[contains(., "Download bounding boxes")]`

Comment: problem :` button = WebDriverWait(driver, 10).until(EC.visibility_of_element_located((By.XPATH, '//a[contains(., "Download bounding boxes")]')))
NameError: name 'WebDriverWait' is not defined`

Comment: @Brahimce Did you add the imports?

Comment: an other error    
` button = WebDriverWait(driver,5).until(EC.visibility_of_element_located((By.XPATH, '//a[contains(., "Download bounding boxes")]')))
NameError: name 'By' is not defined `

Comment: I want to click button "Download bounding boxes" after the load of page

Comment: @Brahimce add `from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By`

Answer (score 1):

The button is under an `<a>` tag so we write code for Xpath:

```
 driver.find_element_by_xpath("//a[. = 'Download bounding boxes']").click()
```

so it finds  the text is "Download bounding boxes" on the website and clicks on it.
In the code above `//` a is written because the button was inside the `<a>` tag we can write `//span`,`//div` as well if the code was under a `span` or `div`tag.